# Copy content from closed work book column

Tags: vba, excel

As said in the title I'm trying to copy data from a column into a new workbook as its a weekly report where the data I add in this column remains valid.

```
Sub copyColData00()

Dim lastRow As Long

Dim myApp As Excel.Application

Dim wkBk As Workbook

Dim wkSht As Object

Dim mnt As String



Set myApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

mnt = InputBox("Enter Filename")

Set wkBk = Workbooks.Open("\\n\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx")

lastRow = wkBk.Sheets(1).Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wkBk.Sheets(1).Range("R1:R" & lastRow).Copy

myApp.DisplayAlerts = False

wkBk.Close

myApp.Quit

Set wkBk = Nothing

Set myApp = Nothing

Set wkBk = ActiveWorkbook

Set wkSht = wkBk.Sheets("Sheet1")

wkSht.Activate

Range("R1").Select

wkSht.Paste

Exit Sub



End Sub
```

My problem is that I want it to past it directly while there I get a prompt that ask if I want to copy all the data in the clip board or not and my second problem is that at
 Set wkSht = wkBk.Sheets("Sheet1")
It gives me the error subscript out of range I've trouble understanding what happens there if someone could help it would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot easier way to do that:

```
Sub copyColData00()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wkBk1 As Workbook, wkBk2 As Workbook
    Dim wkSht As Object
    Dim mnt As String

    mnt = InputBox("Enter Filename")
    Set wkBk1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wkBk2 = Workbooks.Open("\\n\Documents\" & mnt & ".xlsx")
    lastRow = wkBk2.Sheets(1).Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wkBk1.Sheets(1).Range("R1:R" & lastRow).Value = wkBk2.Sheets(1).Range("R1:R" & lastRow).Value 'change which sheet you want for wkBk1

    wkBk2.Close
End Sub
```